# How do I change the Hibernate logging level?

Tags: hibernate, logging

How can I change the Hibernate logging level programmatically?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Hibernate uses [SLF4j](http://slf4j.org/) as it's logging API. Looking at this API I can't find any way to adjust the logging level programatically.

So in my opinion you have to use the underlying runtime logging system directly. This depends on what you have configured. When using log4j this would be something like

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;

...    

Logger log = Logger.getLogger("org.hibernate.SQL");
log.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
```

But remember that going this way your code is dependent on the underlying logging implementation.

Comment: (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger()

Comment: And if you want to print parameter values additionally:
`((org.apache.log4j.Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("org.hibernate.type")).setLevel(Level.TRACE);`

Answer (score 13):

You can use standard log4j functionality:

```
Logger.getLogger("org.hibernate").setLevel(Level.<what level you require>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Log4j functionality:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;

Logger.getLogger("org.hibernate").setLevel(Level.<what you want>);
```

Answer (score 0):

If using JPA, you can add:
`<property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="[LOG LEVEL]" />`
to your persistence.xml.

Source:
https://eclipse.dev/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_logging_level.htm